# How a task in linux which is waiting for a lock, wakes up once the lock is released by the another task?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

lets say task A in linux is waiting for a lock and on that time the specified lock is held by another task B. so task A will be in wait queue. now once the task B are done then release the lock. Now my doubt is how task A get to know that the lock is available and how is it wake up??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is ... *kernel*.

Locking and unlocking is done by dedicated kernel functions. When unlock is called, the kernel checks if there's anyone waiting to lock and if there is, they get the lock and get woken up by the kernel.

Comment: As you have said kernel(collection of lot of modules and sub modules) does that, but can you explain which part of the kernel does exactly (like scheduler) and which are all the modules involved in this mechanism..?

Comment: @zair See books on Linux (e.g. Understanding the Linux Kernel) and the source code.